# Resolve many Layout in ASP.NET MVC 4 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

- I have a problem with layout in ASP.NET MVC razor
- I have 3 _Layout, a page is "Product.cshtml", and a parameter
  "somethingPara"
- I want with a value of parameter "somethingPara", a page will use a
  some _Layout.
- But I don't know how to implement.
- Someone can help me.
- Thank so much.

Comment: what have you implemented so far?

Comment: I don't understand you question?
Now i can only one _Layout, but i want my page, will use other template each value of "somethingPara"
Ex : if (somethingPara == 1){
_LayougePage = "_Layout1"
}else if (somethingPara == 2){
_LayougePage = "_Layout2"
}

Comment: please edit the question to add your work thus far. Code in comments is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

This way you use different layout.

```
@{
if(ViewBag.somethingPara =1)
{
   Layout = "~/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminPopupLayout.cshtml";
}
else
{
    Layout = "~/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

}
```

Comment: I dont understand. If i am right then right click my answer. If i am wrong then explain me why I wrong. Thats how I get more knowledge.